# IPHONE: How to crosscompile teserract ocr 3.01 and how to use it in my app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ocr, cross-compiling, tesseract

I am new to iphone development. I have gone through some websites to find solution for the cross compile teserract ocr, but i couldn't make that to work. Can anyone help me please. And please tell me the step by step procedure that how to include that teserract cross compiled ocr library to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/#comment-240) you can begin